# How can I install the XNA framework ins Microsoft Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, xna-4.0

I'm starting to learn programming and now I want to try to make some simple games. I would like to use the XNA framework in Visual Studio 2017 but I don't know how to include it in Visual Studio.

I installed the XNA framework 4.0 version.

The Xna framework should be included in Visual Studio, at the moment it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the guide to do this you need this installer to do so
http://flatredball.com/visual-studio-2017-xna-setup/

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting to learn how to programm games i would very much recommend you unity in front of xna. It's more Lightweight to understand for beginners and there are tons of tutorial related to unity, game development techniques and c# in general!

Else i would check the installation options of your VS Installation or download the XNA SDK directly and install it as an MSI. AFAIK Microsoft does have a xna setup somewhere.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, so unity works with c# too? I will definitely check it out then :)

Comment: Unity works, but XNA works too. It's really dependend on what you're aiming for, Unity is very hand-holding and does already a lot for you, without having to understand why. Hence why I've preferred building from the ground up with XNA. It's probably more annoying to work with from the beginning, but In the end, I've understanded more of C# with XNA than I did during my Unity experience, So it doesn't hurt to try them both out.